# How to install python3.6 on aws ec2 instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

**This question is specifically for installing version 3.6 of python. Not any other versions.**

I'm using aws' [amazonlinux](https://hub.docker.com/_/amazonlinux) docker image and trying to install python3.6 on it. It worked less than a month ago simply using `yum install python3.x86_64`, but now it seems that all python3 versions are using python3.7 as shown below:

```
bash-4.2# sudo yum list | grep python3 
python3.i686                           3.7.4-1.amzn2.0.3              amzn2-core
python3.x86_64                         3.7.4-1.amzn2.0.3              amzn2-core
python3-Cython.x86_64                  0.27.3-2.amzn2.0.2             amzn2-core
python3-debug.x86_64                   3.7.4-1.amzn2.0.3              amzn2-core
python3-devel.x86_64                   3.7.4-1.amzn2.0.3              amzn2-core
python3-libs.i686                      3.7.4-1.amzn2.0.3              amzn2-core
python3-libs.x86_64                    3.7.4-1.amzn2.0.3              amzn2-core
python3-lit.noarch                     0.7.1-1.amzn2.0.1              amzn2-core
python3-openmpi.x86_64                 4.0.1-11.amzn2.0.1             amzn2-core
python3-pip.noarch                     9.0.3-1.amzn2.0.1              amzn2-core
python3-rpm.x86_64                     4.11.3-40.amzn2.0.3            amzn2-core
python3-rpm-macros.noarch              3-23.amzn2                     amzn2-core
python3-setuptools.noarch              38.4.0-3.amzn2.0.6             amzn2-core
python3-test.x86_64                    3.7.4-1.amzn2.0.3              amzn2-core
python3-tkinter.x86_64                 3.7.4-1.amzn2.0.3              amzn2-core
python3-tools.x86_64                   3.7.4-1.amzn2.0.3              amzn2-core
python3-wheel.noarch                   0.30.0a0-9.amzn2.0.3           amzn2-core
```

Comment: are you pulling the latest container? the older [tags](https://hub.docker.com/_/amazonlinux?tab=tags) probably have 3.6 installed on them

Comment: @aws_apprentice I am using the same image I used a month ago and a month ago it still had python3.6 available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please enable ius repository and install python36u

https://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-how-to-install-the-ius-community-repository/

```
yum install python36u
```

Comment: Thanks AWS PS. But there is no package python36 in the epel list. Which one should I be installing?

Comment: looks like python36 has been removed from epel and replaced by ius

Comment: IUS doesn't build packages for Amazon Linux.

https://ius.io/faq#is-ius-compatible-with-amazon-linux

Answer (score 1):

You can just download and build from [source](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/).

The steps are as follows:

1. Install gcc and sqlite-devel `yum install gcc sqlite-devel`
2. Extract the downloaded archive and cd to the directory
3. Configure with `./configure --enable-optimizations`
4. And finally `make altinstall`.

`altinstall` avoid replacing the default `/usr/bin/python`.

That's it!

Comment: Amazon official container uses Red Hat based distros. You cannot use apt-get.

Comment: Thanks @sayan I might give that a try. Can't believe there's not a simpler solution to such a common problem...